# Will system call scratch XMM registers on Linux x86_64?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel

Will **system call** scratch XMM registers on Linux x86_64?

I've searched some document about abi, but none of them mentioned XMM registers in system calls.

Where can I make sure of that?

Comment: Did you check the [ABI specification](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf)?

Comment: IIRC, SSE/AVX are forbidden in the Linux kernel.

Comment: @MargaretBloom wrong. There are various SSE optimized versions of functions, mostly crypto and raid related. See for example the `xor_sse*` stuff in [xor.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/xor.h) or the entire [xor_avx.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/xor_avx.h) Also notice the `kernel_fpu_begin`/`end` calls.

Comment: @Jester, true. They are merely discouraged.

Comment: @fuz yes, but I'm not sure I covered all details.